# Send an email from Drupal interface?

Tags: emails

How can I send an email from the D7 UI to specified email addresses?

I want to type in some text, type in some recipient addresses, and click send to send it from the site's address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way could be using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) and a custom content type.

The content type should have a title which can be used as the email title, a body for email body, and a field to hold email address(es) (or perhaps a reference field to site users or roles).

Then configure a new rule. Select new content event, add a filter to restrict to defined content type, then as an action select send email. Map the proper inputs and you are done.

Comment: for sending email to non users you can replace your user reference field with email address field or you can have both ,

Answer (score 1):

There are innumerable ways to accomplish this. If you don't need to track the outgoing mail (keeping a copy on the server), I would do it this way:

- in a custom module, create a custom form containing the email elements (to, body, etc) inside a custom page
- use a module such as [Simple Mail](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_mail) to create the actual mail

> A module to simplify sending emails with Drupal.
>
> There are many great modules for complex email handling and sending
>   scenarios, or email templating, and Drupal core handles emails pretty
>   well by itself. However, for many sites, a radically simplified email
>   sending system is helpful.

This is probably a more advanced method fo accomplishing this, but if you haven't yet, and want to get into custom module creation, this is farely simple and would prove a good starter project. This has an advantage of being small and lightweight

Comment: This is the answer to the original question. But if all recipients can be Drupal users, it will smoothen out the user experience. See my answer.

Comment: @Daniel - that's irrelevant, since OP doesn't want to limit it to Drupal users according to his comment on your answer, so I fail to see why you would bring it up in my answer - It's not our job to push an agenda on UI and UX - they clearly want it a specific way with maximum versatility

Comment: Geoff, my answer was not supposed to be THE answer. Merely a suggestion. I pointed this out in the first sentence of both my answer, and made mention of it in my comment above.

Comment: @Daniel fair enough, but I don't get that out of anything you have written at all, just a miscommunication then

Answer (score -1):

Drupal isn't exactly meant as an email client, instead try doing it in a Drupal way.

For example:

- Enter a username for a recipient, add body, then send. Give [Views Send](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_send) a shot.
- Go to a user page, add body, then send. As in the bundled contact module.

Comment: Please, a little more elaboration on your first bullet...also not necessarily sending to users.

Comment: This answer is for Drupal users only.

Comment: when including modules as part of an answer, please include a link to and description of the module for easier reading